# Find/replace within a line only if line does not contain a certain string (awk)

Tags: awk

I'm trying to reproduce an awk command using different syntax.  I have a file (`test.txt`) that looks like this:

```
>NAME_123_CONSENSUS
GACTATACA
ATACTAGA
>NAME2_48_TEST
ATAGCGA
```

and I'm hoping to replace all occurences of "A" with "1" using different syntax of awk.  I can solve this using the following line:

```
awk '!/_/{gsub("A", "1"); 1' test.txt
```

However, I cannot get the same result using a `for` loop,

```
awk '{for(j=1; j<=NF; j++) if ($j ~ "_") print; else print gsub("A","1")}' test.txt
```

nor using the following input

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ "_") print $0; else print gsub("A", "1"); }' test.txt
```

Both of these last commands give the following output.  Why are they giving different output and what am I missing to make both of the last two commands give the desired output?

```
>NAME_123_CONSENSUS
4
4
5
>NAME2_48_TEST
3
```

Comment: `gsub` doesn't return the replacement, it modifies the argument string (which defaults to `$0`) in place. It returns the number of replacements that were made.

Comment: if needed, gawk's gensub would return the modified string..

Comment: Thanks.  So it's not possible to do this with gsub within a loop in `awk`?

Comment: Just wondering, this looks very much like a FASTA file, but with out the `>`. Just to be sure, did forgot those?

Comment: Yes, it's from a FASTA file.  Edited the example now.  Do you recommend a different approach using a FASTA file?

Comment: Using a loop for the input you've posted doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to do that? Do you actually have multiple fields on a line and want to process each field one at a time? If so then show **that** as your sample input/output.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton - yes, I agree with your point that it doesn't make sense to use a for loop here as the for loop isn't for lines.  I was interested in a solution as a learning exercise as I simply couldn't see why I wasn't able to get it working using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `gsub()` function here. The `sub()`/`gsub()` function return the number of substitutions made and *not* the modified string. You set the string to modify as the last argument and print it back

```
awk '{ for(j=1; j<=NF; j++) if ($j ~ "_") print; else { gsub("A","1",$0); print } }'
```

That said your first command is most efficient/terse way of writing this. Notice you were missing a `}` in the OP. It should been written as

```
awk '!/_/{ gsub("A", "1") }1'
```

Or use `gensub()` available in GNU Awk's that return the modified string that you can use to `print`. See more about it on [String-Functions of GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
awk '{ for(j=1; j<=NF; j++) if ($j ~ "_") print; else print gensub(/A/, "1", "g") }'
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  And the third command I posted could be edited like so `awk '{ if ($0 ~ "_") print; else {gsub("A", "1", $0); print} }' test.txt`

Comment: @p-robot technically yes but you'd never actually write that command line, you'd write it as `awk '!/_/{gsub(/A/, "1"} 1' test.txt` instead (note that the first arg for gsub() is a regex, not a string). Without knowing exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish by doing this differently it's very hard to advise you on the right approach.